# Using NPAPI( libflashplayer32.so ) and OpenGL together

Tags: opengl, npapi

I am building a 3D application by using OpenGL for Linux systems.

I also want to use flash with it. On Windows , you are able to render a flash file to an off-screen target , create a texture from it and then use with D3D/OpenGL.

So by using NPAPI and dlopening libflashplayer32.so , that is what I want to do : to create a texture each time from the rendered swf and use it in my OpenGL application.

Do you know how I can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible, but pretty tricky.  I have done it once, not for generating OpenGL textures, but for creating an animation.

You have to pretend to be a browser loading the flash plugin, then read out frames from the X11 window the flash plugin paints in.  This can be pretty slow, so might not be practical depending on your use case.